# Why does my registration for Mean.JS not stay logged in?

Tags: mean, meanjs

When I refresh the page, I get logged out.

https://blooming-plateau-98618.herokuapp.com/

Sorry to make you register to see the error. It's just a fresh install of MeanJS https://github.com/meanjs/generator-meanjs

I get no errors when I "inspect page" and hit "console." I also am not seeing anything in the heroku logs.

Answer (score 3):

I found out the error was with beautify'ing the code. It separated this important line

```
var user = {{user | json | safe}};
```